# Modem and PC refuse to work together

Tags: windows, router, connection, modem

A friend of mine asked me to help him with his network, strangely his ADSL modem always disconnects whenever he plugs in his computer. But as long his computer is offline the modem works just fine for wireless or wired connections from other devices.

Things we tried:

- Reinstall windows (XP & 7 both tried)
- Change Ethernet cable
- Change physical port on router
- New network card
- Different power sources, current stabilizer (not sure about the correct term)

Yet, the router insists on not letting the internet work: the ADSL lamp turns off as soon the computer is plugged in and so does the internet lamp (accessing the router page works though).
We even tried connecting a different pc in his room to rule out that his room is haunted or something (it wasn't and the other pc worked).

What can be the cause of this? the router is a "ZTE ZXV10 W300" ([English Manual](http://www.otenet.gr/hd/HTML/adsl/zte/ZTE%20ZXV10%20W300%28B%29%20v5.2%20User%20Manual_EN.pdf))

Comment: they are already connect to different power points, we also tried getting a current stabilizer (not sure about English name)

Comment: Yes, the router remains on, just the ADSL/Internet lamps turn off (I edited the question)

Comment: As I said as soon it's connected whether u plug it in while it has already booted into windows or you plug it in while it's booting up. As soon you turn the pc on, the lamps go off.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I may have miss-read. So, I hope the last question. If the PC is on, with wireless turned off and no cable connected to the router, does the router remain functioning?

Comment: Yes, as long you don't connect them the router works. Thanks for taking time to help :)

Comment: I assume this is a DNS issue - I think the router is trying to get internet details from the PC. Maybe DHCP is disabled? Open the router home page and check to see that it is responsible for DHCP. On your PC, make sure you're using the router as the default gateway and as the primary DNS

Comment: I tried toggling DHCP on & off and nothing changed. also tried using random ip's and changing MAC addresses :/

Comment: Did you read page 24 and 25 and 26 of your manual to make sure this is OK? Or, are you able to do a factory reset on the router?

Comment: Factory reset didn't change anything (besides having to enter the DSL credentials again ofc)

Comment: Is the network card driver up to date (meaning, up to date from the manufacturers website, not via MS updates)

Comment: The second network card we tried had up to date drivers, so I don't think the problem lies here either. I am going to pay my friend a visit in half an hour and try everything you suggested here again carefully and report if I notice anything.

Comment: Anything to report then?

Comment: @Dave Rook Had to leave for work a little earlier than scheduled, He'll use wireless meanwhile. I'll tag you when I get back (or answer the question myself if he finds a solution) :)